# EditText cursor blinking prevents espresso test from running

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test a UI that has one EditText which has focus. There is a caret blinking every second or so, and this makes the UI thread active almost all the time.

Espresso believes the UI is not ready and waits forever before giving up.

> androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 572 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed ASYNC_TASKS_HAVE_IDLED.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I have noted this happens only on a very old device that I use for testing (Galaxy Nexus) but doesn't happen on a more recent device (Huawei P10+). So I'm not sure this is related to surface updates.

When triggering surface updates from the developer options, something odd shows up: the Galaxy Nexus has surface updates only when the caret is blinking, while the Huawei has its surface constantly updated (ugh!). But the tests work fine on Huawei.

Answer (score 0):

We just hit this but on a webview.  Trial and error finally showed it is related to the soft keyboard being there.

We use emulators so just disable the keyboard with this:

adb shell settings put secure show_ime_with_hard_keyboard 0

No more AppNotIdleException when testing our webviews.
Not sure what you can do on the devices but perhaps this will give you a clue.